# Передать indexpath collectionview (popover) в основной viewController

Tags: uicollectionview, objective-c, объекты

Здравствуйте!

Есть `ViewController`, в нем есть `navigationbar` с кнопкой, при нажатии которой открывается `popover`, внутри которого collectionview с элементами.

В классе `PopoverCollectionViewController` настраиваю `collectionview`:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 45;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

         int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 45;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@".png"]];

    if (cell.selected) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1]; // highlight selection
    }
    else
        {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Default color
        } 
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

Этот popover вызывается в классе editSchemeViewController по ibaction при нажатии этой кнопки след. методом:

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender {      
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UICollectionViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Popover"];

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.actionButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 440)];
}
```

Нужно передать из класса `PopoverCollectionViewController` `indexPath.item` выбранных элементов в класс `editSchemeViewController`, чтобы в нем сразу же отобразить выбранные элементы, хотелось бы так, кликнул на элемент в `collectionView`, который в popover, элемент сразу отображался на основном виде приложения, из которого вызывается popover.

Подскажите, как это реализовать, желательно на примере.

Comment: Никто не может помочь? Или я мало информации дал?

Comment: Привет. Используйте протокол/делегат для обмена данными между вьюконтроллерами.

Пример: http://hashcode.ru/questions/379541/objective-c-обновить-uitableview-из-другого-viewcontroller-а

Comment: Благодарю, что направили, будем пробовать и разбираться, но с протоколами еще немного плаваю. )

Comment: На самом деле там ничего сложного нет.